# How can I put constraint to a foreign key using two attributes?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, constraints

There are two tables `Staff` and `Patient`.

`Staff` has a few columns and two of them are `Staff_ID` and `Category`.
`Patient` also has a few columns related to his/her appointment and two of them are `Nurse_ID` and `Doc_ID` AND both of them are foreign key referencing `Staff_ID`.

A `Staff_ID` is `Doc_ID` if `Category='Doctor'` and it is a `Nurse_ID` if `Category='Nurse'`.

```
create table Staff
(
    Staff_ID varchar2(7) check (Staff_ID like 'SF%') primary key,
    Staff_Name varchar2(20),
    Category varchar2(20) check (Category in ('Nurse', 'Lab Technician', 'Helper', 'Attender', 'Doctor'),
    Designation varchar2(20) check (Designation in ('Staff Nurse', 'Head Nurse', 'Technician', 'Senior Technician', 'Junior Attender', 'Senior Attender', 'Junior Doctor', 'Senior Doctor'),
    DOB date,
    Contact integer(10),
    Address varchar2(50),
    Dept_No  varchar2(7) foreign key references Department(Dept_No)
);

create table Patient
(
    Pat_ID varchar2(7) check (Pat_ID like 'P%') primary key,
    Doc_ID varchar2(7) foreign key references Staff(Staff_ID) check (Category='Doctor'),
    Nurse_ID varchar2(7) foreign key references Staff(Staff_ID) check (Category='Nurse'),
    Consult_Room_No integer(4),
    Date_Of_Appointment date,
    Time_Of_Appointment time
);
```

How to create same foreign key for 2 different columns?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong in your scripts:

- Missing right parenthesis
- Wrong data types ( there is no `time` data type in Oracle )
- You can reference a primary key with two foreign keys , but they must be independent of each other.
- You can check category in patient, because that field is not part of the table. However, you can do that using a trigger.
- Although I did not change the definitions in my example below, you should consider to add NOT NULL constraints for those fields that require such behaviour ( all of the ones that belongs to constraints of any kind )

Use this instead ( for the purpose of the example, I use `alter table add constraint` as statement rather than put everything in the `create table` statement)

```
create table Department ( dept_no varchar2(7) ) ;

alter table department add primary key ( dept_no ) ;

create table Staff
(
    Staff_ID varchar2(7) primary key ,
    Staff_Name varchar2(20) ,
    Category varchar2(20) ,
    Designation varchar2(20) ,
    DOB date ,
    Contact number(10) ,
    Address varchar2(50) ,
    dept_no  varchar2(7)  
);

alter table staff add constraint fk_stf_on_dpt  FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) references Department(dept_no) ;

alter table staff add constraint chk_stf_id check (Staff_ID like 'SF%'),

alter table staff add constraint chk_des_na check (Designation in ('Staff Nurse', 'Head Nurse', 'Technician', 'Senior Technician', 'Junior Attender', 'Senior Attender', 'Junior Doctor', 'Senior Doctor') ) ;

alter table staff add constraint chk_cat_na check (Category in ('Nurse', 'Lab Technician', 'Helper', 'Attender', 'Doctor') ) ;


create table Patient
(
    Pat_ID varchar2(7) ,
    Doc_ID varchar2(7) ,
    Nurse_ID varchar2(7) ,
    Consult_Room_No number(4),
    Date_Of_Appointment date,
    Time_Of_Appointment date
);

alter table Patient add primary key ( Pat_ID ) ;

alter table patient add constraint chk_nur_id check ( nurse_id in ( 'Nurse' ) );

alter table Patient add constraint fk_pat_id foreign key (Doc_ID) references staff(staff_id) ;

alter table Patient add constraint fk_nur_id foreign key (Nurse_Id) references staff(staff_id) ;
```

Test run

```
SQL> @ddl.sql
SQL> create table Department ( dept_no varchar2(7) ) ;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table department add primary key ( dept_no ) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> create table Staff
  2  (
  3      Staff_ID varchar2(7) primary key ,
  4      Staff_Name varchar2(20) ,
  5      Category varchar2(20) ,
  6      Designation varchar2(20) ,
  7      DOB date ,
  8      Contact number(10) ,
  9      Address varchar2(50) ,
 10      dept_no  varchar2(7)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table staff add constraint fk_stf_on_dpt     FOREIGN KEY (dept_no) references Department(dept_no) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table staff add constraint chk_stf_id check (Staff_ID like 'SF%') ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table staff add constraint chk_des_na check (Designation in ('Staff Nurse', 'Head Nurse', 'Technician', 'Senior Technician', 'Junior Attender', 'Senior Attender', 'Junior Doctor', 'Senior Doctor') ) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table staff add constraint chk_cat_na check (Category in ('Nurse', 'Lab Technician', 'Helper', 'Attender', 'Doctor') ) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> create table Patient
  2  (
  3      Pat_ID varchar2(7) ,
  4      Doc_ID varchar2(7) ,
  5      Nurse_ID varchar2(7) ,
  6      Consult_Room_No number(4),
  7      Date_Of_Appointment date,
  8      Time_Of_Appointment date
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> alter table Patient add primary key ( Pat_ID ) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table Patient add constraint chk_pat_id check (Pat_ID like 'P%') ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table Patient add constraint fk_pat_id foreign key (Doc_ID) references staff(staff_id) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> alter table Patient add constraint fk_nur_id foreign key (Nurse_Id) references staff(staff_id) ;

Table altered.

SQL>
SQL> insert into Department values ( 'SF100' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into Staff ( Staff_ID , dept_no ) values ( 'SF1001' , 'SF100' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into Patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P1000' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1002' ) ;
 insert into Patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P1000' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1002' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST_PERF.FK_NUR_ID) violated - parent key not
found


SQL> insert into Staff ( Staff_ID , dept_no ) values ( 'SF1002' , 'SF100' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>   insert into Patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P1000' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1002' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> insert into Staff ( staff_id , dept_no )  values ( 'SR10003' , 'SR103' ) ;
insert into Staff ( staff_id , dept_no )  values ( 'SR10003' , 'SR103' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST_PERF.CHK_STF_ID) violated

SQL> insert into staff ( staff_id , dept_no , category ) values ( 'SF1004' ,  'SR103' , 'Head Nurse' ) ;
insert into staff ( staff_id , dept_no , category ) values ( 'SF1004' ,  'SR103' , 'Head Nurse' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEST_PERF.CHK_CAT_NA) violated


SQL> insert into staff ( staff_id , dept_no , category ) values ( 'SF1004' ,  'SR103' , 'Nurse' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Then add this trigger to control the behaviour of staff_id depending on the category ( you can rewrite the trigger the way you want to )

```
create trigger t_patient before insert or update on patient
for each row 
declare
vcategory_nurse pls_integer;
vcategory_docid pls_integer;
begin
   if inserting or updating 
   then 
    select count(category) into vcategory_nurse from staff where staff_id = :new.doc_id and category = 'Nurse';
    select count(category) into vcategory_docid from staff where staff_id = :new.nurse_id and category = 'Doctor';
    if vcategory_nurse != 0
    then 
       raise_application_error(-20001,'Staff Id is Doctor not Nurse');
    end if; 
    if vcategory_docid != 0
    then 
       raise_application_error(-20001,'Staff Id is Nurse not Doctor');
    end if; 
   end if;
end;
/
```

Test case of the trigger

```
SQL> insert into patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P10005' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1001' ) ;
insert into patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P10005' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1001' )
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Staff Id is Nurse not Doctor
ORA-06512: at "TEST_PERF.T_PATIENT", line 15
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TEST_PERF.T_PATIENT'


SQL> insert into patient ( Pat_ID , Doc_ID , Nurse_ID ) values ( 'P10005' , 'SF1001' , 'SF1004' ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select staff_id , category from staff ;

STAFF_I CATEGORY
------- --------------------
SF1001  Doctor
SF1002
SF1003
SF1004  Nurse
```

Comment: They don't let me ask two question in a day. But I have a new issue.                                                                                                                 I have to create a trigger that gives 5% extra discount if bill_amt > 100000 but mine doesn't seen to be working.                                                                                                            create trigger t_discount 
before insert or update on Hospital_Bill
for each row
begin
    if new.Bill_Amount > 100000
    then 
        set new.discount = new.discount + 5;
    end if;
end;

Comment: try this `create trigger t_discount before insert or update on Hospital_Bill  for each row 
 begin  if :new.Bill_Amount > 100000  then 
     :new.discount = :new.discount + 5; 
 end if; 
 end;` . new values are referenced as `:new`

Comment: Errors: TRIGGER T_DISCOUNT
Line/Col: 4/23 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; indicator
The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.

Comment: create trigger t_discount 
before insert or update on Hospital_Bill
for each row
begin
    if :new.Bill_Amount > 100000
    then 
        :new.discount := :new.discount + 5;
    end if;
end;                                                                                                                                 trigger created. Thank you. I hope it works.

Comment: let me know if it does not ;)